# Firebase packages' names are missing in Package Manager window on Unity 2020.2.0b12

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I added the code below to `Packages/manifest.json`, but I can't see Firebase packages in the Package Manager window.

```
"scopedRegistries": [
    {
        "name": "Game Package Registry by Google",
        "url": "https://unityregistry-pa.googleapis.com",
        "scopes": [
            "com.google"
        ]
    }
]
```

[screenshot of missing Firebase packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCeZI.png)

In the picture above, installed packages are shown, but non-installed are invisible. Why?

- OS: macOS Big Sur 11.0.1
- Unity: 2020.2.0b12
- Firebase SDK: 6.16.1

At least, I had could see the all packages in the window on Unity 2020.1.11f1, regardless of installed or no.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use a BETA version then and rather stick to the latest stable build? Also which package do you mean exactly since in the screenshot there is the Firebase package listed ..

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://forum.unity.com/threads/package-manager-not-showing-my-registries-option-in-2020-2-0b14.1020805/). And it's still present in Unity 2020.2.1f1.

Comment: Have you found any workaround or fix???